# Divs inside inline-block div does not fit parent size

Tags: html, css-float, css

I am creating a input form and I have two child and 1 parent div:

```
<div style="border: dashed; border-width: 1px; padding: 25px; display:inline-block; background-color:Aqua">
<div style="float: left; background-color:Orange">
</div>
<div class="expenseItems" style="background-color:green">
<div>
</div>
```

I want two child divs side by side and parent  covering his childs widths exactly thats why I used inline lock . [image: Here] is what i get until now

Comment: A copy-paste of your code does not look like the result image you supplied, maybe something odd is going on with the content inside? http://jsfiddle.net/8XPTu/1/

Comment: just use clearfix on the parent http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">Orange DIV</div>
  <div class="expenseItems">Green DIV</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.parent {
  border-style: dashed;
  border-width: 1px;
  padding: 25px;
  display:inline-block;
  background-color: aqua;
}
.child {
  float: left;
  background-color: orange;
}
.expenseItems {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: green;    
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QGwtc/

OR use [clearfix](http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html) on the parent

Comment: this causes full width parent which I don't want to prefer

Comment: @woryzower maybe you could explain more clearly what you're trying to achieve. Did you see my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/QGwtc/ ? The parent only stretches to the width of it's contents. Isn't that what you were looking for?

Comment: It worked now. Source of the problem was margin property preexisting in expenseItems class. It was my fault not to specify it in question. Could you explain why this worked? e.g. why we used  a float :left in first child  and a inline-block in second child

Comment: @woryzower you can have both children using float:left and it would be the same result, same goes for display:inline-block but that would add a space between the children, because html will render that line break between them as a single blank space.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you're not closing your 2nd div properly, this might also cause some problems.

```
<div class="expenseItems" style="background-color:green">
<div> <!-- </div> -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

## [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zxGxX/)

Apply `display: inline-block;` to your child divs instead of parent div. To avoid spacing between divs set `margin: -4px;`

Like this:

```
<div class="parent">
<div class="child"></div>
<div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

css

```
.parent{position: relative; width: 100%;}
.child{display: inline-block;}
```

**Notes:**

1. Avoid inline styles.
2. border style is wrong. `border: dashed` use:   `border-style:
   dashed;` or use shorthand properties like this    `border: 1px
   dashed black;`
3. care for your unclosed div

   ---

If you want to apply float properties for your element check this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zxGxX/1/)

Note: `display: inline-block;` to parent div is necessary here. And float to each child divs are necessary here.

Comment: This requires a static `width`, while the question states that he put `inline-block` on the parent in order to have it stretch it its content.

Comment: Yeah, for that purpose I have linked a demo at last. without the width http://jsfiddle.net/zxGxX/2/

Comment: I'm getting same behaviour if  I use your second approach. When I removed float left on expenseItems , expenseItems aligned with first child but  parent didn't cover expenseItem

Comment: for second approach you need to set float value for each.

Answer (score 0):

You have to float out the second child div to make it stick side by side with the first div child [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tQTUc/)

```
<div style="border: dashed; border-width: 1px; padding: 25px; display:inline-block; background-color:Aqua">
<div style="float: left; background-color:Orange">
</div>
<div class="expenseItems" style="float:left;background-color:green">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: -1 In your jsfiddle link, the second <div> is **not** floated (effectively proving yourself wrong), and the container is full width instead of stretching to contents as specified in the question.

Comment: OK, but this new demo doesn't really illustrate anything, and judging by the text and the image in the question, placing the content next to each other is not the problem.

Comment: but he said he wanted two children div to be side by side contained by the parent div, but if you are talking about the width... he already set a `padding` so the container should be bigger than the amount of two divs width + 25px x2
am i missing something here?

Comment: I think we can both agree that the question is quite clumsily worded, but I believe he's asking why the second div is overflowing the aqua colored container (rather than making it stretch)

Answer (score 0):

Remove `display:inline-block` from parent and use `float:left` for `expenseItems`. I hope it works.